# Possible solutions for matrix similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that matrix $A \in M_n$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ with $0$ or $1$ diagonal entries. I read the textbook and it says that there are $n+1$ such different diagonal matrices. However, as I expect, if each entries can select values $0$ or $1$, we should have $(2!)^n$ such kind of matrices.

Could you please point out what is wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for example, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1\\&0\\&&0}, \pmatrix{0\\&1\\&&0}
$$
are similar.

Comment: To expand on this a bit, permuting the rows/columns of a matrix produces a similar matrix, so what matters is the _number_ of ones and zeros, not their arrangement.

Comment: @amd Thank you very much for the very important comment